# How create to string to sign for blob to generateSharedAccessSignature in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to create hmac from string_to_sign for Azure bloc to **generateSharedAccessSignature**  but it giving me an error "Signature fields not well-formed."

Below is my sample string

```
String data = sprintf("%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s",
            ["r",
            "2020-11-17",
            "2020-11-19",
            "/blob/myAccount/test/member-pic/member-993.png",
            "",
            "",
            "",
            "2017-04-17"]);

  //get hmac string
 String data = base64Encode(mac.convert(utf8.encode(data)).bytes);
```

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas

Comment: Yes, above string they need to for blob access

Comment: Could you please provide the whole code and entire error message?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using JAVA as your programming language, and you want to generate a SAS token with `Read` permssion and 2 days valid time. If so, you can just use Azure Storage SDK to generate it and get a SAS token directly, try the code below :

```
            String connString = "<storage account connection string >";
            String containerName = "<container name>";
            String blobName = "<file name>";

            BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connString).buildClient();
            BlobClient blobClient = client.getBlobContainerClient(containerName).getBlobClient(blobName);

            BlobSasPermission blobSasPermission = new BlobSasPermission().setReadPermission(true); // grant read
                                                                                                   // permission
                                                                                                   // onmy
            OffsetDateTime expiryTime = OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2); // 2 days to expire
            BlobServiceSasSignatureValues values = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(expiryTime, blobSasPermission)
                            .setStartTime(OffsetDateTime.now());

            System.out.println(blobClient.generateSas(values));
```

Maven dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
      <version>12.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```